# Node application on bluemix giving 502 Bad request gateway

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

i deployed node application on bluemix. app i starting on localhost:3000 but when access through http://apppoc.mybluemix.net/ giving me 502. any thoughts on this

in logs i find this

```
22 error code ELIFECYCLE
23 error errno 137
24 error SmartApp@1.0.0 tsc:w: `tsc -w`
24 error Exit status 137
25 error Failed at the SmartApp@1.0.0 tsc:w script 'tsc -w'.
25 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm     installed.
25 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the SmartApp     package,
25 error not with npm itself.
25 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
25 error     tsc -w
25 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
25 error     npm bugs SmartApp
25 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
25 error     npm owner ls SmartApp
25 error There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 137, true
```

Comment: Include the code, esp around how you set the port/host on bluemix.  It won't be 3000.  You normally use process.env.PORT.

Comment: where do i set this. i am using npm run script with lite-server to start the app.